# SVN plugin for eclipse:How to warn user for other uncommitted changes?

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin

We are using svn plugin for eclipse. We have a young team and they are not very familiar with svn and eclipse. Sometimes someone checks in just one file and forgets about checking in another file which results in build failure. I looked up but I could not find any way to warn the users if there are another files which are uncommitted. Can someone please tell how can the users be warned while committing if there are other files which needs to be committed.

Comment: That feature could be very annoying; what about all the other random cruft that typically appears in a working copy (object files, txt files, test data, etc.)?

Comment: Those files can be added to SVN:IGNORE. Isn't it?

Comment: That's true.  Although in my experience, the number of different file extensions I end up with once I'm done debugging some code is large!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the plugin you are using (Subclipse or Subversive), your people should learn how to work with Subversion inside eclipse. Here are some tips that may help here:

- Use Mylyn and the integration into your issue tracker to do task-oriented work. Mylyn cares about what is in scope and will commit only the changes that belong to the current task to do.
- Show your people the synchronize perspective and how to use it:

  - Check all changes and decide if they are relevant or not.
  - Mark the entries that should *never* go to Subversion as to be ignored.
  - Commit then, and give a meaningful log message (what is changed (semantically, not syntactically).

This is not really an answer to your question, but I don't think there is an option for doing that, and I don't think that would help if it would be there.